# What is the role of std::forward_iterator_tag?

Tags: c++, vector, standard-library

Upon profiling an application, I bumped into that piece of the standard library implementation shipped with gcc 4.7.1. It is `include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc`:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
template<typename _ForwardIterator>
  void
  vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
    _M_range_insert(iterator __position, _ForwardIterator __first,
          _ForwardIterator __last, std::forward_iterator_tag)
  {
     …
  }
```

I noticed that the last argument of the function signature is just a tag, and I started wondering why it was here. A quick look at [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/) shows that `std::forward_iterator_tag` is an empty structure. What is its role here? Clearly it's useless to the function, and it might waste a register, or some space on the stack. So why?

Comment: Possibly to distinguish between different `_M_range_insert` overloads? [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) seems a little better, and has an example on how the tag structures can be used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes. And that is also an answer. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg While distinguishing the overloads is certainly right, the actual overloads and their use might be more important than the tags provided by the standard, namely `_Int_iterator_tag`. (ever tried to roll your own `std::vector` implementation? :-))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### In a nutshell: Tags are for overloading, for optimization.

Take a simple `advance` as example, you might design:

```
template<class II, class D>
void advance(II& i, D n){
    while( n-- ) ++i;
}
```

However it have `O(n)` complexity, which is not acceptable when you have a `random_access_iterator`. So you may change your design like this:

```
template<class II, class D>
void advance_II(II& i, D n){
    while( n-- ) ++i;
}

template<class RAI, class D>
void advance_RAI(RAI& i, D n){
    i += n;
}

template<class II, class D>
void advance(II& i, D n){
    if(is_random_access_iterator(i)) // not yet designed
        advance_RAI(i, n);
    else
        advance_II(i, n);
}
```

However the *version* of function to use is decided at run-time, so we try to let compiler decided which method to choose at compile-time. So we give iterators **tags**. There are five tags:

```
struct input_iterator_tag {};
struct output_iterator_tag {};
struct forward_iterator_tag : public input_iterator_tag {};
struct bidirection_iterator_tag : public forward_iterator_tag {};
struct random_access_iterator_tag : public bidirection_iterator_tag {};
```

Now you can do this:

```
template<class II, class D>
void __advance(II& i, D n, input_iterator_tag){
    while( n-- ) ++i;
}

template<class RAI, class D>
void __advance(RAI& i, D n, random_access_iterator_tag){
    i += n;
}

template<class II, class D>
void advance(II& i, D n){
    __advance(i, n, iterator_traits<II>::iterator_category());
}
```

Comment: This is *not* about advancing iterators, because it need not be done. In fact, you cannot even advance pure input iterators like this without invalidating them. The tags are about calling `reserve` for all iterators that support `std::distance` or just inserting for plain input iterators or redirecting to `insert(pos,count,value)` if the "iterators" actually are integers. See my answer for more details.

Comment: My first sentence: *"Take a simple advance as example... "*. OP is asking about the need of `std::forward_iterator_tag`, and the idea of tags is the same for `insert` and `advance`. Obviously it is better to use a **simple** method as an **example** to illustrate the **idea** of tags.

Comment: While I agree that a simple example to illustrate the idea is a good choice, I don't think that the actual use case at hand is so much more complex than the simple example you provided. Though I was wrong about the invalidation of input iterators on increments - I apologize for that.

Comment: I have a book *at hand*, where I had learned these. On the other side, I cannot find where `_M_range_insert` is used, it's not *at hand* for me. And, though maybe insert is not *much* more complex, it is *more* complex.

Answer (score 6):

To distinguish between different `_M_range_insert` overloads.

[This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) seems a little better, and has an example on how the tag structures can be used.

Comment: The important bit is that the tags types are related by inheritance. You can pass a `random_access_iterator_tag` to the `_M_range_insert` overload which expects a `forward_iterator_tag`, because that's just a derived-to-base conversion.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of quoting your link..

> Empty class to identify the category of an iterator as a forward iterator:

It is used as a tag to identify the kind of iterator, so that the functions, here `_M_range_insert` can act appropriately. Since it is a type name, it can be used to trigger different overloads.

In my impl, I have

```
void _Insert(const_iterator _Where, _Iter _First, _Iter _Last,
            _Int_iterator_tag)

void _Insert(const_iterator _Where, _Iter _First, _Iter _Last,
            input_iterator_tag)

void _Insert(const_iterator _Where, _Iter _First, _Iter _Last, 
            forward_iterator_tag)
```

Among other overloads.

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of template metaprogramming machinery and it is used to choose appropriate overload based on traits of arguments, so for example if you have random access iterators you can take advantage of that and check distance between them and reserve before insert. On the other hand if you only have forward iterators checking distance would be O(n), so you don't do it, just push back, which can result in multiple relocations and therefore be slower.
Also compiler will optimize out these empty structs, so there is no runtime penalty.

Comment: I don't know what the implementation actually does, but I guess it will rather take the O(n) distance check than the O(N) copies on reallocation.

Comment: thing is reallocation is possible, but not guaranteed and cost of checking distance is guaranteed, so it comes down to amortization considering average use. and I think most commonly you are inserting way less elements than vector already contains. anyway this was meant as an example for tags usage and key point is it gives you information if distance(it1, it2) is O(1) or O(N), which you wouldn't have otherwise and how you use this info isn't as important

Comment: you're right arne, it does check distance in my implementation, i picked bad example, still there are other differences

Comment: the differnce is that pure input iterators cannot check the difference, and I think the more important tag is the `_Int_iterator_tag` Karthik mentioned, wich is used for the `(size_t, value_type)` overloads.

Answer (score 1):

There are several overloads for insertion into a vector, some of them are duplicated for the constructors. Two of those overloads have a conflict if the vector elements are of integral type:

```
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value );

template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

If you have a `vector<int>` and call `vec.insert(vec.bgein(), 5, 4)`, you surely mean to insert 5 times the value 4. But overload resolution will see the template and call that one, deducing `InputIt` to be `int`.

To solve that problem and some other behavioral stuff, the implementors of the standard library have invented some traits and a bunch of tag classes. The traits is a template metafunction that will give three different tags, like Karthik T said in his answer:

- `_Int_iterator_tag` if `InputIt` is of integral type
- `forward_iterator_tag` if `InputIt` is a forward iterator (that includes random access iterators)
- `input_iterator_tag` if `InputIt` is an iterator type that is not a forward iterator

You will then have a bunch of overloads of `_M_range_insert`, taking the different tag types as additional parameters, each doing the Right Thing, meaning

- The overload for the Int-Tag will redirect to the first non-templated overload of `insert` (or its implementation)
- The overload for forward-iterators calls `reserve(std::distance(first,last))` and copies the elements from the iterator range after that
- The overload for plain input iterators just copies the elements, maybe causing multiple reallocations. It cannot call `reserve`, because the input iterators can be evaluated only once (thing e.g. of istream iterators)

The templated insert method will then look conceptually like this:

```
template< class InputIt >
iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last )
{
  return _M_range_insert(pos, first, last, InsertIteratorTraits<InputIt>::tag_type());
}
```

Comment: It's not the role of traits. **If overload resolution is a problem, STL would simply change the name.** STL is not such a bad library. Maybe you happened to be correct in `insert`, but you won't in other function.

Comment: I never said the tags had the role of traits. The tags are used for overload resolution, and the traits are used to generate tags from the template parameter.

Comment: It appears that we are thinking on different things. You think tags are used for overload resolution, while I think tags are used for overload resolution *for optimization*.

Comment: Ah... I tried to cancel down-vote but system forbade me. (You last voted on this answer 23 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited)